# Why does the doctor help Ray Breslin at last?

Tags: plot-explanation, escape-plan

In the movie [Escape Plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_Plan_%28film%29), why does the doctor, who comes into jail for the treatment of the prisoners, help the hero i.e. Ray Breslin (Sylvester Stallone) and brings a chopper in the end. What is the reason behind helping Ray with such a big heart?

Comment: That jail look scary even from the comfort of my home. How do you think a  person, especially one who wants to help people, would feel in there? From what I know the chopper+troops are from one of Sylvester's friends, he just delivered the message and took them to the spot.

Comment: The doctor is present in the chopper when it arrives there.... why would he do that?

Comment: You are kind of over thinking this movie... Throughout the movie there are scenes (funny or not) that remind you this is only a movie and Stallone and Arnold are having fun doing it. It's not the historical type (like Unbroken) that shows you the harsh conditions and true human nature. It's a dynamic funny movie, enjoy it

Answer (score 5):

If you remember, Ray Breslin (Sylvester Stallone) tells him about a book and asks him to read a particular page and to remember his oath.

> **Ray:** In Hobbes' office is a book, Compromising Correctional Institution Security by Ray Breslin. On page 88 is a
>   detailed description of Cell Block C at Lewisburg Federal Prison.
>
> **Doctor:** Guards.
>
> **Ray:** Check it out. And remember your oath.

The doctor, of course, reads that book and there was something in that book which made him help Ray (Sylvester Stallone). However, what that thing was was never explained in the movie.

> **Doctor:** I saw the book. How did you know?
>
> **Ray:** I'm Ray Breslin. I wrote the book.
>
> **Doctor:** Doctors are men who prescribe medicines of which they know little to cure diseases of which they know less for men of whom they know nothing at all. What do you want me to do?

The doctor might have recognized Ray and knew that he is innocent and was trapped in the jail for no reason. That might be the reason he decided to help Ray.

Answer (score 0):

It was the oath that made all the difference:

[image]

By referring to page 88 of his book, he proved to the doctor that he's Ray Breslin, who himself is the designer of the security, suggesting that there might be "something rotten in the state of Denmark".

By re-reading the Hippocratic Oath, doctor remembered that he swore to protect his patients **"from harm and injustice"**. By proving that he actually is Ray Breslin, it was clear that some injustice is going on there. The doctor had left enough conscience and will to act and offer Ray Breslin a help:

> "Doctors are men who prescribe medicines of which they know little to
> cure diseases of which they know less for men of whom they know
> nothing at all.
>
> What do you want me to do?"